# Equality on Objective-C typedef enum in Swift

Tags: enums, swift

I'm working with the Facebook Objective-C SDK in Swift and I'm trying to compare an FBSessionState value with a value from the enum. However I get the compiler error:

> Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments

I'm essentially trying to accomplish:

```
if state == FBSessionStateOpen { ... }
```

I'm able to work around this by comparing against the value...

```
if state.value == FBSessionStateOpen.value { ... }
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work more like a Swift enum?

Comment: Try `if state == .FBSessionStateOpen`

Comment: No luck, according to Swift docs this should have worked but it appears the enum was not created with the NS_ENUM macro. The error is: Could not find member 'FBSessionStateOpen'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could unwrap the enum and constants with '.value' to get the underlying integer, which should be switchable:

```
switch x.value {
  case Foo.value:
}
```

Maybe this is a bug and apple fix it in future releases.

Answer (score 4):

With the Beta4 update, the .value workaround no longer works. There doesn't seem to be another easy workaround without changing Facebook's SDK.

I changed all the Facebook enums to use the NS_ENUM macro, so that you can use Swift syntax the enums.

```
if FBSession.activeSession().state == .CreatedTokenLoaded
```

These changes were merged into [pgaspar's Facebook fork](https://github.com/pgaspar/facebook-ios-sdk), which includes other fixes for Swift compatibility.

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', :git => 'https://github.com/pgaspar/facebook-ios-sdk.git'
```

Comment: Any clue as to why Facebook have yet to *fix* this? Pgaspar's fork risks going stale as Facebook commit further changes..

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Nikolai Nagorny's answer, this is what worked for me:

```
if (device.deviceType.value == TYPE_BLUETOOTHNA.value)
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift automatically maps Obj-C enums to its own style of `enumName.caseName` structure. For example, if the `enum` is named `FBSessionState` and there is the `FBSessionStateOpen` case, it will map as `FBSessionState.Open` in Swift.

The `==` operator will work for comparing Swift enums.

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen for FBSessionState. Using FBSessionState.Open or even FBSessionState.FBSessionStateOpen causes a "Expected member name or constructor call after type name" - I think the enum mapping only occurs when enums are defined with NS_ENUM macro as stated in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_15

Comment: @DennyFerra Ah you're probably right about that. Since most Obj-C enums are just integer values it should be pretty easy to recreate it in Swift and just use that instead.