# Comparison of Objective C type def enum in Swift not working

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have problems with enum comparison of Philips Hue SDK (Obj-C framework imported in Swift with bridge header).

This is the Obj-C enum:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 Copyright (c) 2013-2014 Koninklijke Philips N.V.
 All Rights Reserved.
 ********************************************************************************/

#define SDK_ERROR_DOMAIN @"com.philips.hue.sdk"

typedef enum {
    // Resource parsers
    INVALID_JSON = 1,
    INVALID_ARGUMENTS = 2,

    // PHHttpRequester
    NO_CONNECTION = 21,
    INVALID_PARAMETERS = 22,
    INVALID_PARAMETERS_MISSING_URL = 23,
    INVALID_PARAMETERS_MISSING_METHOD = 24,
    INVALID_PARAMETERS_INVALID_METHOD = 25,

    // Bridge Resource Cache Storage
    LIGHT_ID_NOT_FOUND = 41,
    SCHEDULE_ID_NOT_FOUND = 42,
    GROUP_ID_NOT_FOUND = 43,
    INVALID_DATA = 44,

    // Pushlinking
    PUSHLINK_NO_CONNECTION = 60,
    PUSHLINK_TIME_LIMIT_REACHED = 61,
    PUSHLINK_NO_LOCAL_BRIDGE = 62,

    // Unsupported
    UNSUPPORTED_IN_THIS_VERSION = 80,

    // Domain objects
    INVALID_DOMAIN_RESOURCE = 90,
    INVALID_DOMAIN_RESOURCE_ARGUMENT = 91,
    UNSUPPORTED_DOMAIN_RESOURCE_ARGUMENT = 92,

    CLIP_ERROR = 100
} CLErrorCode;

/**
    General purpose NSError derived object that is used for SDK errors
    Enum of error codes identifies error types
 */
@interface PHError : NSError

@end
```

In the Obj-C sample project they compare the enum error code like this:

[image]

My swift code looks like this and I got the following error:
[image]

I found this SO question: [Equality on Objective-C typedef enum in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134649/equality-on-objective-c-typedef-enum-in-swift)

But it's not working for me. I already tried...

```
error.code.value = PUSHLINK_NO_CONNECTION.value
error.code = PUSHLINK_NO_CONNECTION.value
error.code = .PUSHLINK_NO_CONNECTION
...
```

Nothing is working :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use rawValue?
Something like this:

```
error.code.value == CLErrorCode.PUSHLINK_NO_CONNECTION. rawValue
```